# Is there any race condition for 2 or more threads doing read from different files into the same buffer?

Tags: c, multithreading, race-condition, unistd.h

If there are **n** threads doing a **read(uniqe_file[k], buffer, sizeof(buffer))** (k=1..n) (**read** from **unistd.h**) is there a chance that the content of **buffer**, after the threads are done, is messed up by having a combination of values from various files?

For example:
**n** = 2
**buffer** is a char array
unique_file[1] contains "abc"
unique_file[2] contains "123"
Then, can buffer contain, at the end, something like "a2c", or "12c" or even worse cases like "1a2"?

And, can you provide an explanation for the possible scenarios?

Comment: I think you are basically asking whether the `read` system call is thread safe.  Almost certainly.

Comment: From the man page of read (section 2) (BUGS heading) I understood that is thread & process safe with respect to update on the file offset. But I saw nothing regarding the buffer.

Comment: No, the buffer is shared, it is global

Comment: Oh, that's a strange design if you want things to be thread safe.  Use different buffers if you want things to be thread safe.  There is no possible way for it be thread safe if you are writing to a shared buffer from multiple threads at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any race condition for 2 or more threads doing read from different files into the same buffer?

Yes: two threads attempting to write the same bytes is a race condition *by definition*. The resulting program exercises undefined behavior.

> can buffer contain, at the end, something like "a2c", or "12c" or even worse cases like "1a2"

Undefined behavior means: *anything* can happen.

It's unlikely that you'll observe anything other than `abc` or `123`, but it's possible for all of the above to happen. The conditions for `1a2` in particular are exceedingly unlikely, but it *can* happen.

Other unlikely possibilities: `111`, `231`, `aca`, etc. To see why these are possible, read [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/).